# PPA not listing all available php packages

Tags: bash, apt, php

I have added the corresponding PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

I have run `sudo apt update`

But it's only showing candidates for `php7.4`

`sudo apt install -y php8.0` produces `E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0'`

Output of `lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

Why is it not showing `php8.0` nor `php8.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.04 is an [interim release](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) that is only supported for 9 months and has stopped receiving support as of January 2022. Looking in the [PPA itself](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php), the releases with published packages are:

- 21.10 (Impish)
- 20.04 (Focal)
- 18.04 (Bionic)

While I cannot know the reasoning behind the decisions, it appears that the PPA maintainer removes builds of the packages for versions of Ubuntu that are no longer supported. I recommend upgrading to the latest interim release as 21.04 is no longer receiving updates so your system will fall behind on important security patches.

Comment: That must be it. Nicely spotted